# Cygwin: help installing automake

Tags: windows-10, cygwin

I've been trying to install automake on cygwin and it doesn't work, I've re-run the setup selecting the packages and reinstalling them but it doesn't work.I've also tried installing it via: apt-cyg install automake with no result.

```
$ automake -v
```

> /usr/bin/automake: /usr/bin/automake-1.15: /usr/bin/perl: intérprete erróneo: No such file or directory
>   /usr/bin/automake: línea 186: /usr/bin/automake-1.15: No error

Answer (score 1):

Your installation has some problems and you need to reinstall same packages.

At least you need to reinstall the `perl_base` as the `perl` program belongs to it:

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/perl
perl_base-5.26.2-1
```

I suggest you to run `cygcheck -cv` and reinstall all packages that are not OK using the cygwin setup program.